# Change Font Color in Label Box Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I will display data from multiple columns in Label box. is there a way to change the font color of data from Column S when displayed? and the other text is black by default.

```
EventLabel.Caption = EventLabel.Caption & Range("F" & i) & vbCrLf & "-" & Range("S" & i) & vbCrLf & "-" & Range("T" & i) & vbCrLf & "-" & Range("U" & i)
```

Comment: Did jou already look at [the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.label.forecolor)?

Comment: I tried but I get an error "object doesn't support property method" @Gert-JanM

Comment: Can you show your code where you are attempting to change the colour?

Comment: The label control has ForeColor property. But it does not support multiple colors. You have to split the label into 3 labels.